# Formatting an ISO 8601 timestamp string in Flask template / Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, momentjs

I've been using Flask-Moment to format DateTime objects in my Flask templates. This works fine; however, I run into problems when trying to format a string timestamp (specifically ISO 8601 ... e.g. '2022-03-23T18:11:52Z')

Flask-Moment throws an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` when I try:

`{{ moment('2022-03-23T18:11:52Z').format('L LTS') }}`

It seems it only accepts a DateTime object and there's no way to specify an alternative input timestamp parameter.

As an alternative, I can use Moment in Javascript, but this gets overly messy when trying to update multiple `document.getElementById.innerText()` / `document.write()`.

What's the cleanest way to handle ISO 8601 string formatting in Flask templates? Is Javascript really the only option?

Comment: What do you mean by "cleanest" way and "messy" (in objective terms)?

Comment: @TylerH ideally I'd like to do this using python within the template, rather than JavaScript. I want the minimum amount of JavaScript possible.